# smooth scroll to DIV after click on Submitt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I would like to smooth scroll to part called "result" after click on Submit button. But only result I get is just normal scroll, not smooth scroll.

Here is piece of HTML code:

```
<form action="index.php#result" method="post">
    <div id="search-box">
     <?php include 'submitt.php'; ?>
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter city name">
        <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" id="SubmitButton">
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the result section code:

```
<section id="result" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <p class="intro-text">Text.</p>
      <?php include 'q.php'; ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

A set following in JavaScript:

```
$("#SubmitButton").submit( function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#result").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Can you please help how to get the smooth scrolling effect after click on Submit button? 
I use Bootstrap framework there.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

see this example http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/8tLdq/2129/

I updated your fiddle

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Hi Keval, thank you your example. I create similar file like you, then I changed `<a id="myButton">button</a>
<div class="div">` from your code to `<form action="#myDiv" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter city name">
 <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" id="SubmitButton">
</form>`
Then I changed javascript like this`$("#SubmitButton").submit(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});`

I think the problem can be with form. Can you please let me know your opinion? Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Really saved a LOT of my time :)

Answer (score 1):

[Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) never lets me down. Here is his solution. Again, I can't stress enough that this isn't my solution, it belongs to a legend. Check out the origin by clicking his name above.

```
// Scroll to specific values
// scrollTo is the same
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// Scroll certain amounts from current position 
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // could be negative value
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// Scroll to a certain element
document.querySelector('.hello').scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

In my opinion, this is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Smooth Scrool Plugin: https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#SubmitButton").submit( function() {
    $('body').scrollTo('#result',{duration:2000});
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your script. I tried it, but no success, it is still scrolling without smooth effect. 

Should I change section id="result" to div id="result" ?

    `<section id="result" class="container content-section text-center">`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have discovered the simplest method.
The problem here is, after submission page refreshes. As the refresh is browser side, it is not suggested to interfere browser action.

By emprical, I found the position of my element as div, table, etc..
In my case 1000px was fine and I used this and worked fine:

```
if(isset($_POST['input_name']))
{       
    // your action codes here ....
            
echo '
      <script>
      window.scrollTo(0, 1000);
      </script>';                           
}
```